# Where did these Heroku apps come from?

Tags: heroku

I have created a local git repository called phantomjs123 and I'm trying to deploy to Heroku:

```
me@my-PC /f/EasyPHP-12.1/www/phantomjs123 (master)
$ heroku apps
=== My Apps
phantomjs123
protected-waters-9718
serene-mesa-1437
```

As you can see 2 additional apps have been created. I tried to delete them but when I do

```
me@my-PC /f/EasyPHP-12.1/www/phantomjs123 (master)
$ ls
bin  nbproject  procfile
```

They don't appear to exist locally. Can someone explain what these other apps are and how to remove them?

Comment: Have you tried going to the heroku website, logging in, and deleting those other apps through there?

Comment: I ended up using this method under the setting button to delete all 3 of the apps. I'm going to try to start over..

Answer (score 0):

To destroy apps on Heroku you can do:

```
heroku apps:destroy <APPNAME>
```

Mind you, they would only exist as a result of doing a `heroku create`.

Comment: what happened? What was the output?

Comment: This was last nite, but something to the effect that the app didn't exist.I ended up using the method under the setting button to delete all 3 of the apps.